# Parsing amazon reviews separated by <span> tags

Tags: python

I am trying to readin some data from a .csv file. An example of the data looks like this:

```
4.0 /gp/customer-reviews/RKMO449VT48H3?ASIN=1491590173  4.7573214851  Stars "<span class=""a-size-base review-text"">I'm a hard-science science  fiction fan ....  (Btw, I like those stories, too, but good ones are hard to find.)<br/><br/>Somebody did their homework on this one -- and that's what  stands out above all else.</span>"
```

If I try to read the data like this:

```
with open("Andy-Weir-The-Martian.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
 df_total = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=",")
```

It throws the following error:

> File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1865, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:23325)
>   pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 32 fields in line 3, saw 35

Any thoughts on what are best practises for reading this data into python?

Comment: is there more than one review in the csv? there is a comma in the comment/review which you are using as a delimiter. can you add a few more lines of the csv?

Comment: I know, but that doesnt work... I need to get rid of the span part...

Comment: First off, your csv values are separated by tabs or spaces not `sep=","`.

Comment: _Expected 32 fields in line 3, saw 35_-- That's because your last column has a string with interior quotes, which makes it look like 3 strings.  Try `quotechar='"'`

Answer (score 0):

This means that the file CSV file has different layout on 3rd row.You could Ignore 3rd line by using the option 'error_bad_lines'. Also I dont see see comma in your sample data. It may be a tab ?

```
 df_total = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=",", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Note that offending lines will be removed when error_bad_lines=False used. If you don't want ignore bad lines, investigate why 3rd row has a different number of columns